# Is D powerful enough for these features?

Tags: metaprogramming, d

For the longest time I wanted to design a programming language that married extensibility with efficiency (and safety, ease-of-use, etc.) I recently rediscovered D and I am wondering if D 2.0 is pretty much the language I wanted to make myself. What I love most is the potential of metaprogramming; in theory, could D's [traits](http://dlang.org/traits.html) system enable the following features at compile time?

1. Run-time reflection: Are the compile-time reflection features sufficient to build a run-time reflection system a la Java/.NET?
2. Code conversion: Using a metaprogram, create C#/C++/etc. versions of your D program every time you compile it (bonus point if doc comments can be propagated).
3. Traits. I don't mean the [metaprogramming traits](http://dlang.org/traits.html) built into D, I mean [object-oriented traits for class composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29). A D program would indicate a set of traits to compose, and a metaprogram would compose them.
4. Unit inference engine: Given some notation for optionally indicating units, e.g. `unit(value)`, could a D metaprogram examine the following code, infer the correct units, and issue an error message  on the last line? (I wrote such a thing for [boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) so I can assure you this is possible in general, program-wide):

   ```
   auto mass = kg(2.0);
   auto accel = 1.0;                      // units are strictly optional
   auto force = mass*accel;
   accel += metresPerSecondSquared(9.81); // units of 'force' and 'accel' are now known
   force += pounds(3.0);                  // unit mismatch detected
   ```

Answer (score 7):

> Run-time reflection: Are the compile-time reflection features sufficient to build a run-time reflection system a la Java/.NET?

Yes. You can get all the information you need at compile time using [__traits](http://dlang.org/traits.html) and produce the runtime data structures you need for runtime reflection.

> Code conversion: Using a metaprogram, create C#/C++/etc. versions of your D program every time you compile it (bonus point if doc comments can be propagated).

No, it simply isn't possible no matter how powerful D is. Some features simply do not transfer over. For example, D has an inline assembler, which is 100% impossible to convert to C#. No language can losslessly convert to all other languages.

> Traits. I don't mean the metaprogramming traits built into D, I mean object-oriented traits for class composition. A D program would indicate a set of traits to compose, and a metaprogram would compose them.

You can use [template mixins](http://dlang.org/template-mixin.html) for this, although they don't provide method exclusion.

> Unit inference engine: Given some notation for optionally indicating units, e.g. unit(value), could a D metaprogram examine the following code, infer the correct units, and issue an error message on the last line? (I wrote such a thing for boo so I can assure you this is possible in general, program-wide):

Yes, this is straightforward in D. There's [at least one implementation](http://www.dsource.org/projects/scrapple/browser/trunk/units/si2.d) already.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest the converter should support all features including assembly language :), But just the idea that D could inspect the code deeply enough to *attempt* a conversion.

Comment: This way one could write a program in D, C++ and C# simultaneously by limiting oneself to a certain subset of D. Naturally you'd have to e.g. convert lambda template arguments into runtime arguments, or auto-replicate templates with different arguments, according to limitations of the target language. Such a conversion tool could make D more attractive for writing certain libraries, especially algorithms and exotic data structures, though I recognize it need not necessarily be accomplished with metaprogramming.

Comment: It is possible I believe, but that would require language translator at compile-time... It would be an enormous project...

Comment: @PeterAlexander I didn't mean a unit-checking system of the sort that has already been done in C++, I meant unit *inference* which is far easier to use and therefore far more practical in everyday code. The linked implementation appears to encode dimensions into the data type. An ideal inference engine would not use special data types, it would track units independently of data type. Plus it could support not just SI units, but arbitrary concepts like "bytes", "pages", "inches", "pixels", "local coordinates", "global coordinates".

Comment: This kind of unit inference is very similar to the code-conversion example; ideally it would use whole-program analysis, and it would require minimal changes to the code whose units you want to check.

Comment: @Qwertie: In that case the answer is no, D cannot supply an extra orthogonal type-checking system on top of the existing one. You need to use types for static checking.

Comment: Hmmmm. In that case I wonder how hard it would be to use the compiler front-end as a library, and insert a compile step somewhere to accomplish this. It would be slower of course... and I hope DMD, GDC and LDC don't all use different front-ends.

Comment: @Qwertie: They all use the same front end, but it currently isn't usable as a library. I believe it's on the radar though as something we'd like to do.

Comment: @Qwertie: Regarding units, the linked library does use inference (as I understand the term) to automatically generate whatever types are needed. Mix that with extensive use of `auto` and you basically only needs to explicitly state types for "literals", printing and class members. All of which you really need to know anyway. -- Also, it wouldn't be spectacularly hard to allow adding arbitrary new dimensions to the system via a sorted tuple of key value pairs, not that I've ever seen that as a good idea. (BTW, I'm the author of that library)